# How to close a project in Xcode 7

Tags: macos, xcode7

Is it possible to close a Project without closing Xcode? if so, how?

The reason for this is that when I open another project, it leaves the old one open and then opens the new project in a different desktop on El Capitan 10.11

Comment: Just click red x in the top left. It will not close Xcode, but it will close project. The you can open another one, without multiplying the screens

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option described in the comments is not the most convenient.
You have other appropriate options:
1. If you have playground opened in the Xcode you can click "File" from the left top -> select "Close <>". You will see that only you playground was closed but Xcode window not.

2. You can also close the whole Xcode windows. From "File" select "Close playground".
3. Last one is to close the Xcode, just select "File" -> "Close window"

The same is for projects: "Close project" should be clicked.

Please fin the information below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/CreatingProjects.html

Hope this will somehow clarify